# Set a filter with tshark

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am trying to do this: set Wireshark filter to "http contains site.do" in tshark. I'm not sure how to do this using just the command line version. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tshark -Y "http contains site.do"
```

Comment: So it says "Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets." As far as I understand it, that means that I would have to filter them after I collect them. How should I go about that (The results are going into a .pcap file), which I display with sudo tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r file.pcap The reason I'm using the command line is that wireshark requires X11, and yosemite doesn't have X11, nor does it support it as far as I understand

Comment: `tshark -r` {your capture file} `-w` {the output file} `-Y "http contains site.do"

Comment: Yosemite doesn't *ship* with X11, but it *does* support it.  Install XQuartz from [MacOSForge](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).

Comment: Or, if you're willing to live with alpha-quality software that doesn't have all the features complete yet, and which has a somewhat different GUI, try the development release, which *doesn't* require X11.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the display filters are different of capture filters. For example you can do it to save http traffic of one host.

```
tshark -f "host www.site.do and (port 80 or port 443)" -w example.pcap
```

You can get more info about the capture filters [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters)

Comment: tshark: Invalid capture filter "host www.test.do" for interface 'Wi-Fi'!

That string isn't a valid capture filter (unknown host 'test.do').

Comment: I did and It is working as expected. You can add the interface with the param -i <interface>